# Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical' adding legend

Tags: r, legend

I am having trouble with a `legend` in `R`. I am working with survival data and I have two kaplan meir curves. I need to identify each one in my plot. I am using legend and this is what I have tried:

```
plot(kmenfprimaria.dos.inicio, ylab="2B. Probabilidad de supervivencia", 
     family="Times Roman", xlab="Tiempo en días", 
     sub="Mediana: LLA 175 IC 95% (142-295); LMA: 159 IC 95% (59-NR). p(log-rank)=0.783",
     ps=3, cex.main=0.9, cex.sub=0.7, cex.lab=0.7, 
     main="Supervivencia por diagnóstico", cex.main=0.9, lty=c(1,2), lwd=2, 
     legend(450, 0.8,legend= c("LLA","LMA"), lty=c(1,2), lwd=2))
```

Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

I dont know what to do to coerce object.

Answer (score 0):

`legend` is not an argument to `plot`, you need to call `plot()` then `legend()` eg

```
plot(kmenfprimaria.dos.inicio, ylab="2B. Probabilidad de supervivencia", 
 family="Times Roman", xlab="Tiempo en días", 
 sub="Mediana: LLA 175 IC 95% (142-295); LMA: 159 IC 95% (59-NR). p(log-rank)=0.783",
 ps=3, cex.main=0.9, cex.sub=0.7, cex.lab=0.7, 
 main="Supervivencia por diagnóstico", cex.main=0.9, lty=c(1,2), lwd=2)

 legend(450, 0.8,legend= c("LLA","LMA"), lty=c(1,2), lwd=2)
```